# Re-use array collection on multiple pages

Tags: angularjs

I currently have 2 pages, `page1.php` and `page2.php`, each of the pages uses a controller that completes its own functions etc.
However there are tabs within the pages that are exactly the same that gets a `promise` from a factory within the `module`. The lists are exactly the same except for querying on different IDs. For example both controllers have this:

```
pageListFactory.getData().then(function (result) {
    $scope.BasicItems = result; $scope.basicItemsList = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.BasicItems, function (BasicItem) {
        angular.forEach(BasicItem['SomeInnerArray'], function (BasicSomeInnerItem) {
             if (BasicSomeInnerItem == VARIABLE_THAT_CHANGES) {
                 $scope.basicItemsList.push({
                     ID: BasicItem.ID, Title: BasicItem.Title 
                 });
             }
         });
     });
});
```

So this code is used, and the `VARIABLE_THAT_CHANGES` is just what changes each time. However as I said it is used on multiple pages, is there a way to create just one function call and then each page just can call a specific bit and send the variable with it?

I tried using `$rootScope` but of course this just clogs and slows, and I'm not exactly happy on constantly using `$rootScope` to pass the `$scope.basicItemsList` around as the list could get quite big.

So is there any way to reuse this code without just copying and pasting it into each controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can re-use it...
Convert the factory to a service, its basically a name change, create a local variable to store the data, update the data on first call, and then grab the data if it exists on the second call.

```
.service('myService', ... stuff ... { // I suggest using a service, as I don't know if a factory would act as a singleton
    var myData = null;

    return {
        getData: function(){
            if(myData != null)
               return myData; // returns data
            else {
               return $http()... // ajax call returns promise
            }
        },
        setData: function(dataToSet){
            myData = dataToSet;
        }
    }
```

Then your controllers:

```
//controller 1
var promiseOrData = pageListFactory.getData();
if(promiseOrData instanceOf Array){ // or whatever data you expect
    $scope.BasicItems = promiseOrData;
    ....
} 
else { // should be a promise
    promiseOrData.then(function (result) {
        pageListFactory.setData(result); // set the data once you get it.
        $scope.BasicItems = result; $scope.basicItemsList = [];
         ....

     }
}
```

In controller 2 you only need to get the data as the returned data will be an array, not a promise

On top of all this, write a directive which will process the data when you pass it along, then you can pass the variableThatChanges and have the directive take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `services` and write the function in that service and pass the variable `VARIABLE_THAT_CHANGES` into it. By this you can reuse the code.